# What are numbers, colons, and count in tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know what count and colons are usually used for when referencing a list, but I am reading a piece of code which seems to use them in a way in which I haven't seen them before.

```
questions = {
    1 : ("str1" , "str2"),
    2 : ("str3", "str4"),
    3 : ("str5" , "str6")
}
for count, question in questions.items():
    print("Question", count)
```

This then returns

```
Question 1
Question 2
Question 3
```

and those numbers change if I change the values before the colons. If I then `print(question)`, it is printed without the number or colon (eg: `(str1, str2)`). Does this mean that the number and the colon are separated from the item in the tuple?

Sorry if this is an obvious question - I am relatively new to using Python. I'm also not certain what the comma does in `for count, question in questions.items():`, but that's a different question.

Comment: `questions` is a dictionary mapping numbers 1, 2, 3 to the tuples `("str1", "str2")` etc. `count` inside the loop are the keys 1,2,3 etc & the `question` is the corresponding tuple in the dictionary.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading a good, basic Python tutorial where you would get introduced to the fundamental structures of the language, like the `dict` your are asking about.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation. If you are "relatively new to using Python" and have a question about how various features of the language work, you should try either a) the official language documentation; b) a tutorial (the documentation includes one, but you can try others); or c) a proper discussion forum, such as https://reddit.com/r/learnpython.

Comment: You can also find some recommendations for tutorials at https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you read up on python dictionaries first. `items()` returns a view object, which contains key:value pairs as tuples in a list. So in your case, when you do:

```
for count, question in questions.items():
```

This is what questions.items() holds:

```
dict_items([(1, ('str1', 'str2')), (2, ('str3', 'str4')), (3, ('str5', 'str6'))])
```

This is how the values of `count` and `question` are updated in every iteration:

```
loop 1: count = 1 and question = ("str1" , "str2")
loop 2: count = 2 and question = ("str3", "str4")
loop 3: count = 3 and question = ("str5", "str6")
```

Which is why in

```
print("Question", count)
```

you see the output as

```
Question 1
Question 2
Question 3
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp is a good resource for getting to grips with the basics of python

Comment: An important note: w3schools is an absolutely terrible ressource. Don't use it, and please don't recommend it, it's inaccurate and often plain wrong. An example that caused someone to ask a question on SO just one hour ago: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_del.asp states that "The del keyword is used to delete objects. In Python everything is an object, so the del keyword can also be used to delete variables, lists, or parts of a list etc." - No, it deletes names/references to objects, not objects. And the end makes one wonder what they call a 'variable'.

Comment: could you link any other website/book? It'll be helpful for anyone else who comes across this

Comment: There are some good recommendations at https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F